# How can I ignore an incoming call using Sofia SIP

Tags: sip, telephony, freeswitch, restcomm, sofia-sip

By ignore I mean to tell the local SIP stack to remove all resources for the incoming call, but not send any SIP message across.

I've trying do that using nua_handle_destroy() for the unanswered sofia handle (i.e. without sending BYE, or answering with an 'error' code), but it seems that Sofia generates a response anyway.

Is there a way to avoid this? I've been able to do that using JAIN SIP stack but not Sofia.

Best regards,
Antonis

Comment: I've tried some experiment with my setup after seeing this question.
If i don't serve any XML to incoming call which get pass after default or public context, it just stays ideal after sending a initial response 100 trying until the caller / initiator gives up.
I'm curious to know your use case :)

Comment: Can't you simply ignore the incoming call event and wait until call expires? What about invoking only nua_handle_unref?. It is simply releasing memory but not reseting protocol state. Anyway beware of this as it may cause some unintended behaviour or memory leak.

Comment: I can try with unref, but I don't want the protocol state to be preserved, as it will likely mess with future calls, right? I want the protocol state destroyed but without sending any messages to the wire. Thanks